# Searching a String in a file

Tags: java, file, loops, syntax

I wish to write a function in Java that searches for a specific String in a text file. Which loop should I use and how? (say it is a while loop, what's the condition?)

Comment: Depends on how you read in the text file.

Comment: Use any loop: `for(;;)`, `while(...)`, `do{ ... } while(...)`. There are several ways to accomplish this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most used loop for this is the `while` loop, because you need to loop and to compare if the string retired from the file is not `null`.
Well, this is said, let's see some code. A solution that you can write is to open your file first in a `BufferedReader` instance then you'll read from it line by line and see if the line contains the string that you are looking for.
If it does, you can use a `boolean` variable and assign it to true, else assign it to false.
You can have something like this in Java :

```
public static boolean findStringFile(String lookingForMe, String pathFile)
{

    boolean found = false;
    try{
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(pathFile));
        try{
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                if (line.contains(lookingForMe))
                    found = true;
            }
        } finally {
            br.close();
        }
    } catch(IOException ioe)
    {
        System.out.println("Error while opening the file !");
    }
    return found;
}
```

This function will get `String lookingForMe` as the first parameter representing the string you're searching in the file, as a second parameter `String pathFile` which represents the file's path (it can be just `nameOfTheFile.extension` when it is in the project's root).

Hope this could help you.

**Edit**

The execution of the following portion of code (below) isn't always successful, if you have a problem with your file (file does not exist or cannot be opened due to privilege or something else) or any other problem, the execution will stop and throw an exception.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(pathFile));

            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                if (line.contains(lookingForMe))
                    found = true;
            }
```

The goal of the "try" is to avoid these kind of problems by displaying a user error message (the one you specified with `system.out.println("Your error message")` ).

The appropriate code (to avoid problems listed above) that you should use is the one with the try block (the first one).

For further explanation about exceptions in Java, i recommend visiting this : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html

Comment: Thank's a lot! this one surely helps. One last question - what's the purpose of the "try" word in the code?

Answer (score -1):

What I usually use is a BufferedReader and create a while loop like

```
while((line = reader.readLine()) != NULL) {
    //do stuff
}
```